# Provide initial best LB to CPLEX OPL warm-start

Tags: cplex, opl

I am applying the warm-start technique in CPLEX 12.10 using OPL (no Java/C++ API) for a MILP minimization problem.
From model 1, I obtained a feasible solution S and a LB value.
Then I injected S as a MIP start for model 2 using Vector API indicated by the [doc](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_script_fc_default_initset.html) and included LB as a constraint (`obj >= LB`).

So far, everything is working. However, from the engine log, I notice that model 2 does not use the provided LB as the first best bound. Hence in the face of difficult instances, model 2 ends with a significantly large MIP GAP, whereas LB is already demonstrated by model 1 to have a much smaller MIP GAP.

Is there any way to **force** CPLEX to use the provided LB value as some cut-off value? In [the official list of parameters](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.10.0?topic=cplex-list-parameters), I found [*lower objective value limit*](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.10.0?topic=parameters-lower-objective-value-limit), but it seems not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
oplModel.Obj.LB=0;
```

in a flow control if Obj is the objective and oplModel the model but that's not always good for convergence.

For instance, the [hybrid lifegame](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/hybrid.mod) gives

```
374
412
412
427
427
431
```

whereas if I use bounds

```
// hybrid CPOptimizer and CPLEX to solve lifegame
//
// warmstart between CPO and CPLEX tu use them both
// 
// the objective is maximize
//
// And in 60s
//
// we get 
// 396 hybrid (hybrid.mod)
// 379 cplex alone (lifegameip.mod)
// 280 cpo alone (lifegamecp.mod)

int nbiter=3;
int n=30;

int values[0..(n+2)*(n+2)-1];
main {

    var n=thisOplModel.n;
   var nbiter=thisOplModel.nbiter;

  var source1 = new IloOplModelSource("lifegameip.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def1 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source1);
  
  
  var source2 = new IloOplModelSource("lifegamecp.mod");
  var cp = new IloCP();
  var def2 = new IloOplModelDefinition(source2);
  
  var opl1 = new IloOplModel(def1,cplex);
  var opl2 = new IloOplModel(def2,cp);
  opl1.generate();
  opl2.generate();
  
  var objValues=new Array(2*5);
  
  for(var iter=1;iter<=nbiter;iter++)
  {
  
  writeln("iter ",iter);
  
  opl1.Obj.UB=450;
  
  // start with CPLEX
  cplex.tilim=10;
  cplex.solve();
  writeln("cplex objective = ",cplex.getObjValue());
  
  objValues[iter*2-1]=cplex.getObjValue();
  
  cp.param.timelimit=10;
  
  // Warmstart in CPO
  var sol=new IloOplCPSolution();
  for(var i=0;i<=(n+2)*(n+2)-1;i++) sol.setValue(opl2.x[i],opl1.x[i]);
  cp.setStartingPoint(sol);
  opl2.Obj.UB=450
 
  // CP Solve
  cp.solve();
  writeln("cpo objective =",cp.getObjValue());
  objValues[iter*2]=cp.getObjValue();
  
  // And warmstart CPLEX
  var vectors = new IloOplCplexVectors();
  // We attach the values (defined as data) as starting solution
  // for the variables x.
  
  for(var i=0;i<=(n+2)*(n+2)-1;i++) thisOplModel.values[i]=opl2.x[i];
  vectors.attach(opl1.x,thisOplModel.values);
  vectors.setStart(cplex);   
}  
  
 writeln("list of objectives") ;
 for(var i=1;i<=2*nbiter;i++) writeln(objValues[i]);
  
}
```

I get worse results

```
0
241
241
332
332
366
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll give it a try

Comment: It seems not working because my objective function is an expression (dexpr), and I got the error "cannot add properties to this value, "[a IloNumExpr]". Although it is possible to bypass the error by creating an artificial variable for the objective function, I'll make some more tests to check the effect.

Comment: Indeed, in order to use .UB you should write an artificial decision variable